Issue with speech-to-text integration in Azure Communication Services
Context: We are building a bot using Azure Communication Services (ACS) and Azure Speech Services to handle phone calls. The bot asks questions (via TTS) and captures user responses using speech-to-text (STT).
Challenges:

User responses are not being captured. Despite setting InitialSilenceTimeout to 10 seconds, the bot skips to the next question after 1–2 seconds without recognizing speech.

The bot does not reprompt the user even when no response is detected.


Help Needed:

How can we ensure accurate real-time speech-to-text capture during ACS telephony calls?

Are there better configurations or alternate approaches for speech recognition in ACS?


Additional Context:

Following the official ACS C# sample.

Using Azure Speech Services and ACS SDKs.


Code Snippet:
// Recognize user speech
async Task<string> RecognizeSpeechAsync(CallMedia callConnectionMedia, string callerId, ILogger logger)
{
    // Configure recognition options
    var recognizeOptions = new CallMediaRecognizeSpeechOptions(
        targetParticipant: CommunicationIdentifier.FromRawId(callerId))
    {
        InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), // Wait up to 10 seconds for the user to start speaking
        EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),     // Wait up to 5 seconds of silence before considering the response complete
        OperationContext = "SpeechRecognition"
    };

    try
    {
        // Start speech recognition
        var result = await callConnectionMedia.StartRecognizingAsync(recognizeOptions);

        // Handle recognition success
        if (result is Response<StartRecognizingCallMediaResult>)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Result: {result}");
            logger.LogInformation("Recognition started successfully.");
            // Simulate capturing response (replace with actual recognition logic)
            return "User response captured"; // Replace with actual response text from recognition
        }

        logger.LogWarning("Recognition failed or timed out.");
        return string.Empty; // Return empty if recognition fails
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError($"Error during speech recognition: {ex.Message}");
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

What We’ve Done:

Created an ACS instance and acquired an active phone number.

Set up an event subscription to handle callbacks for incoming calls.

Integrated Azure Speech Services for STT in C#.


Achievements:

Successfully connected calls using ACS.

Played TTS prompts generated from an Excel file.



Have you checked for codec compatibility between ACS and Azure Speech Services?

Listen for recognition events (e.g., RecognizeCompleted) to get the user's actual response. For ACS, you’ll typically subscribe to events that indicate success or timeout. Update the method to handle such events.

I am already receiving a RecognizeCompleted event where I am using the SpeechRecognizer method.

ACS provides a set of options for speech recognition. Ensuring these are correctly configured is essential.

Using InitialSilenceTimeout you can set a reasonable duration (e.g., 5–10 seconds) to allow users time to respond.

Using EndSilenceTimeout you can set a duration (e.g., 3–5 seconds) that accommodates natural pauses in speech.


var recognizeOptions = new CallMediaRecognizeSpeechOptions(
    targetParticipant: CommunicationIdentifier.FromRawId(callerId))
{
    InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8),
    EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    MaxRecognitionDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), // If the user response is lengthy
    DtmfToneTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) // For fallback DTMF input
};

Here you can route audio streams to Azure Speech SDK for better control and accuracy.

Use the ACS  Call Media  APIs to route live audio streams from the telephony call. Configure the Speech SDK to transcribe audio streams in real-time.

Code:
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("YourSpeechKey", "YourRegion");
speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US"; // Set locale

using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(yourAudioStream);
using var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) => {
    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Recognized: {e.Result.Text}");
    }
};

await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();

Log:


The CallMediaRecognizeSpeechOptions does not have MaxRecognitionDuration & DtmfToneTimeout parameters. I am not entirely sure which specific ACS Call Media API you are referring to.
Based off the provided code, what would be value & configuration for the audio stream?

the above parameters are typically part of other APIs or configurations within Azure Speech Services. configure the audio stream correctly in ACS for effective speech recognition.

What are the proper steps for configuring audio stream in ACS?

you need to use the Call Media Streaming API. This allows your application to capture audio streams from calls for external processing (e.g., real-time transcription with Azure Speech Services).

I will add much more details to the abve answer to make it clear.

I am already using the CallMediaRecognizeSpeechOptions function & using the output as a parameter for the StartRecognizingAsync function. However, the InitialSilenceTimeout configuration still does not work properly as if I provide a value of 10, the bot moves to the next prompt in 1-2 seconds regardless if I say anything or not.
